# AIR app still running when the iphone is blocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, air

I just made a simple game with flash professional 6.0 and adobe AIR sdk 3.4 for iPhone.

The problem is this: when I lock the iphone pressing the power button, the screen switches off as usual, but the music of the game still sounds. If I exit the game pressing the home button it exits fine. Is only when locking the phone with the app opened.

Also, I opted-out of multitasking for my app, so if I close my app with the home button and I reload it, it loads the main menu.

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Comment: You should really listen for app went to background and app went to foreground events. Then you pause your game where it needs too and resume when it comes to foreground. This applies to native developement. I suspect you'll have to do the same using the AIR SDK, but as I've never used it for iPhone I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of reading, it is a very very simple solution, just with this at the start of the app:

```
SoundMixer.audioPlaybackMode  =  AudioPlaybackMode.AMBIENT;
```

With this playback mode, the sound mutes when the app goes to the background.